# I just created a google trigger from ifttt to google calendar How do i view the script

Tags: json, google-api, google-calendar-api, ifttt

I just used ifttt to create a google trigger to add an event when i say something on google home it adds an event on my google calendar. How can I view the JSON script that creates the event?

Comment: Do you mean you want to intercept POST script directly from IFTTT?

Comment: @ChrisChen Yes please

Comment: What is the purpose? If you are not happy with it's API capability, maybe consider building your own one https://ifttt.com/maker

Comment: You can probably use something like Wireshark if you specifically want to see what Google Home is doing. But, yes, I suspect you want to take a look at Maker.